# postgres - violates check constraint error

Tags: postgresql

This is my table creation script, I am checking order_type before assigning any value to order_until field.

```
   CREATE TABLE merchants
    (
      id serial NOT NULL,
      name character varying(100),
      merchant_image bytea,
      merchant_logo bytea,
      merchant_longitude double precision,
      merchant_latitude double precision,
      merchant_address character varying(100),
      merchant_phone character varying(50),
      order_type character varying(15),
      open_until time without time zone,
      order_until time without time zone,
      CONSTRAINT merchants_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
      CONSTRAINT unique_name UNIQUE (name),
      CONSTRAINT merchants_check CHECK (
    CASE
        WHEN order_type::text = 'NO_ORDERING'::text THEN order_until = '00:00:00'::time without time zone
        ELSE NULL::boolean
    END),
      CONSTRAINT merchants_order_type_check CHECK (order_type::text = ANY (ARRAY['TAKE_AWAY'::character varying, 'HOME_DELIVERY'::character varying, 'NO_ORDERING'::character varying]::text[]))
    )
```

when I try to insert values in the table I got error: **new row for relation "merchants" violates check constraint "merchants_check"**
Here is my insert script:

```
INSERT INTO MERCHANTS(NAME,MERCHANT_ADDRESS,MERCHANT_PHONE,ORDER_TYPE,OPEN_UNTIL,ORDER_UNTIL)
VALUES('Test','Test address1','1234567','NO_ORDERING','22:00:00'::time,'20:00:00'::time);
```

Anyone has any suggestion how to fix this problem?

Comment: Have you cleaned the table before trying it? Because if you ran it twice, the constraint is doing its job.

Comment: I have cleaned whole database before running it, I only have problems when I want to insert row where oredr_type is 'NO_ORDERING'

Comment: BTW: I would prefer `check (order_type::text <> 'NO_ORDERING' OR order_until = '00:00:00'::time without time zone )` instead of the `CASE ...` (though I think they are semantically equivalent) Also thes fields should be NOT NULLable, IMHO

Comment: How to write if order_type is 'NO_ORDERING' then order_until = '00:00:00'::time

Comment: Note: It is a check constraint, not an assignment. (a check constraint is a bunch of conditions, resulting in a boolean value)